# In the opposite direction to - OR - in the opposite direction from?

Tags: prepositions

Which of these is correct? The second feels more logical, but I'm really not sure.

Here's the context:

'They took a path away from the house that Jack was glad to see struck off in the opposite direction from the lake.'

Comment: Just going over it in my head, I'd say "from" has a slight edge.  But there would be some context dependency, and in some cases neither "sounds right" and another construction is apt to be chosen.

Comment: The mcguffin is in the opposite direction of/from where I'm going. The mcguffin? It's over there. I'm going in the opposite direction to the north.

Comment: First, I think you want *opposite* to follow *direction*, not precede it.  Second, now that you’ve done that, you no longer need to choose another preposition, since *opposite* is already one and so needs no other.

Answer (score 1):

Both the statements are grammatically and logically right. They depend on their context.

But, the first one seems more logical as you would be viewing the direction from the thrid person angle view. If it was first person angle, then the second would be the appropriate one.

For instance;

1) I went in the opposite direction from the church

2) The office is in the opposite direction to the church.

In (1), it indicates that, you were at the church (First person). And then went to the opposite direction.

In (2), it indicates that, you were not at the church (Third person), but you merely instructed someone about the direction.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're pairing the preposition with *direction*, you would most definitely use *from*.

If your intention is to use the preposition with *opposite*, you could indeed use *to* or *from*, but would still be better off using the latter.

> . . . the direction opposite *to* the church.
>
> . . . the opposite direction *from* the church.

**One more thing**:

> . . . the direction opposite the church.

Sans preposition sounds more natural still.